# How to see entries in the database for my clients under other agents but not me?

Tags: php, sorting, equals

I have had a long problem with this code.  I have posted this question multiple times on SOF but never was able to clearly state the problem but now i can.

I want to be able to see posts by other agents for my clients.  So in this query i shouldn't be able to see the posts added by me for my clients but posts for my clients added by other agents.  Below is what i have been trying.  The good thing is that the code does what i need to but then it shows me posts that are not for my clients too.  So i am not sure where I need to make the tweak?

Code:

```
$type1 = "Added by Other Agents"
$myuserid = My id.  So i am using <> to not show posts added by me for my clients. 

$sql = "SELECT posts.posts_id, accounts.full_name,
agents.agent_name, posts.person_id, posts.why_posts, 
posts.just_date, posts.type, posts.date_time_added FROM 
posts LEFT JOIN accounts ON posts.person_id = accounts.person_id 
LEFT JOIN agents on posts.agent_whois = agents.agent_id WHERE 
(posts.type = '$type1') and  
(posts.added_by <> '$myuserid')"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

if ($result == "")
{
echo "";
}
echo "";


$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0)
{
print("");

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

$postsid = $row['posts_id'];
$agentwho = $row['person_id'];
$agentname = $row['agent_name'];
$reason = $row['why_posts'];
$datetimeadded = $row['just_date'];
$name = $row['full_name'];
$type = $row['type'];


print("");
}

}
```

Comment: It is unclear which field in which table stores client ownership. Can you please clarify which field links you to your clients?

Comment: the accounts table is the clients table. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Why are you joining agents on `posts.agent_whois = agents.agent_id`, but selecting on `posts.added_by <> '$myuserid'`? I suspect the join and the selection should be the same column, e.g. join `agents` on `posts.added_by = agents.agent_id`

Comment: well that table is pulling the posts by those agents for my client.  the reason why i am doing the <> is to not show posts by me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the accounts table stores which agent is associated with a client, then you need to add an additional condition to specify accounts that are only associated to you. Since it is still unclear to me which field that is, let's say it's called `accounts.agent_owner`

In this part of your SQL:

```
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN accounts ON (posts.person_id = accounts.person_id)
LEFT JOIN agents ON (posts.agent_whois = agents.agent_id)
WHERE (posts_type = '$type1') AND (posts.added_by <> '$myuserid')
```

Add:

```
    AND accounts.agent_owner = '$myuserid'
```

Comment: hey thanks.  but that didn't work.  it returns nothing if i add that.

Comment: what is the actual field that associates you with the client?

Comment: accounts.agent_id is the field that would link it.

Comment: so, assuming you changed `posts_type` to `posts.type` and `agent_owner` to `agent_id`, do you get zero results returned or an error message?

Comment: i also created new table called relations where i store the id of the customer and the agent.  So do we have to join that now?

Answer (score 2):

Is there an error in the SQL? You have:

```
$sql = "SELECT posts.posts_id, accounts.full_name,
agents.agent_name, posts.person_id, posts.why_posts, 
posts.just_date, posts.type, posts.date_time_added FROM 
posts LEFT JOIN accounts ON posts.person_id = accounts.person_id 
LEFT JOIN agents on posts.agent_whois = agents.agent_id WHERE 
(posts_type = '$type1') and  
(posts.added_by <> '$myuserid')";
```

It strikes me that it should probably be this:

```
(posts.type = '$type1')
```

I expect that would throw an error if it weren't correct though, so I'm not sure (e.g. "no such column").

Comment: you are right, i must have miskeyed it while trying a few things. thx the problem is still there though!